# How to Show Text on GUI

Tags: python, text, pyqt5

I am trying to make a GUI which takes the characters on the live screen and get the document with that ID. Until now I have completed the character taken period and now I need to add these characters on my UI near the related button but I am stuck.

What I need is to add QT text box near the take button and show the text value on GUI.

How could I do that?

```
import sys
from os import path

import cv2
import numpy as np

from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui

import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string
from gtts import gTTS
import os


pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"


tessdata_dir_config = r'--tessdata-dir "C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata"'



class RecordVideo(QtCore.QObject):
    image_data = QtCore.pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        self.timer = QtCore.QBasicTimer()

    def start_recording(self):
        self.timer.start(0, self)

    
    def timerEvent(self, event):
        if (event.timerId() != self.timer.timerId()):
            return

        read, data = self.camera.read()
        if read:
            self.image_data.emit(data)
    def framesave(self):
        
        read, data = self.camera.read()
        if read:
            cv2.imwrite('a.png',data)
            img=Image.fromarray(data)
            img.load()
            
            text=pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='spa', config=tessdata_dir_config)
        


class FaceDetectionWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.image = QtGui.QImage()
        self._red = (0, 0, 255)
        self._width = 2
        self._min_size = (30, 30)


    def image_data_slot(self, image_data):


        
        self.image = self.get_qimage(image_data)
        if self.image.size() != self.size():
            self.setFixedSize(self.image.size())

        self.update()
    
        
        
    def get_qimage(self, image: np.ndarray):
        height, width, colors = image.shape
        bytesPerLine = 3 * width
        QImage = QtGui.QImage

        image = QImage(image.data,
                       width,
                       height,
                       bytesPerLine,
                       QImage.Format_RGB888)

        image = image.rgbSwapped()
        return image

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.drawImage(0, 0, self.image)
        self.image = QtGui.QImage()


class MainWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.face_detection_widget = FaceDetectionWidget()

        # TODO: set video port
        self.record_video = RecordVideo()

        image_data_slot = self.face_detection_widget.image_data_slot
        self.record_video.image_data.connect(image_data_slot)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        layout.addWidget(self.face_detection_widget)
        self.run_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start')
        layout.addWidget(self.run_button)

        self.run_button.clicked.connect(self.record_video.start_recording)

        self.screenshot = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Snap Shot')
        layout.addWidget(self.screenshot)

        self.screenshot.clicked.connect(self.record_video.framesave)
        self.setLayout(layout)


    
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main_window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    main_widget = MainWidget()
    main_window.setCentralWidget(main_widget)
    main_window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

the text is taken with this this line:

```
   text=pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='spa', config=tessdata_dir_config)
```

and the part that the GUI is created :

```
layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        layout.addWidget(self.face_detection_widget)
        self.run_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start')
        layout.addWidget(self.run_button)

        self.run_button.clicked.connect(self.record_video.start_recording)

        self.screenshot = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Snap Shot')
        layout.addWidget(self.screenshot)

        self.screenshot.clicked.connect(self.record_video.framesave)
        self.setLayout(layout)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt's way of exchanging information is through signals:

```
class RecordVideo(QtCore.QObject):
    image_data = QtCore.pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)
    textChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        self.timer = QtCore.QBasicTimer()

    def start_recording(self):
        self.timer.start(0, self)

    def timerEvent(self, event):
        if event.timerId() != self.timer.timerId():
            return

        read, data = self.camera.read()
        if read:
            self.image_data.emit(data)

    def framesave(self):

        read, data = self.camera.read()
        if read:
            cv2.imwrite("a.png", data)
            img = Image.fromarray(data)
            img.load()

            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(
                img, lang="spa", config=tessdata_dir_config
            )
            self.textChanged.emit(text)
```

```
class MainWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.record_video = RecordVideo()

        self.face_detection_widget = FaceDetectionWidget()
        self.run_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start")
        self.screenshot = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Snap Shot")
        self.text_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.face_detection_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.run_button)
        layout.addWidget(self.screenshot)
        layout.addWidget(self.text_label)

        self.run_button.clicked.connect(self.record_video.start_recording)
        self.screenshot.clicked.connect(self.record_video.framesave)
        self.record_video.image_data.connect(self.face_detection_widget.image_data_slot)
        self.record_video.textChanged.connect(self.text_label.setText)
```